# How to get material-design dialog header with Close & Action

Tags: android, material-design

In Google's Material Design document, it shows a full-screen dialog with a header that contains a X close button and a SAVE button.  Is there a support library way of getting this dialog treatment easily?

[Material Design Components Dialogs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-content)

[image: Full Screen Material Design dialog with header]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a support toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar).  Put it at the top of your layout.

It looks like an actionbar but you can just give the views inside it onClick handlers to handle save and close.

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-action-bar-dialog-using-toolbar/ is a decent enough tutorial on how to.